# How to take HTML user input and query it via Python & SQL?

Tags: python, html, sql, django

Is there a way to take user input from HTML, and use python to run the input through to a SQL database? Does the input need to be parsed? I want the the user to be able to type in a store name, and for it to return relevant rows

```
def search():
    store_search = request.form.get("store")
    if request.method == "POST":
        if not store_search:
            return "please type in a store!"
        else:
            c = conn.cursor()
            c.execute("SELECT * FROM stores WHERE store_name= 'store_search'")
            rows = c.fetchall()
            for eachRow in rows:
                return row
    else:
return render_template("search.html")
```

HTML:

```
{% extends "main_page.html" %}
{% block title %}
Search
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" 
                 name="store" placeholder="store" type="text"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">search</button>
            </div>
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>{{ store }}</h1>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple app in `flask` that receives user input and scans the items returned from a `SELECT` query in `sqlite3`:

First, create the user form. You can use `ajax` with jquery for a dynamic response:

In `search.html`:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body> 
    <input type='text' name='query' id='query'>
    <button type='button' id='search'>Search</button>
    <div id='results'></div>
 </body>
  <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#search').click(function() {
       var text = $('#query').val();
        $.ajax({
        url: "/search",
        type: "get",
        data: {query: text},
        success: function(response) {
        $("#results").html(response.html);
       },
       error: function(xhr) {
        //Do Something to handle error
       }
     });
   });
  });
  </script>
</html>
```

In `app.py`

```
import flask
import sqlite3
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return "<a href='/search'>Search</a>"

@app.route('/search')
def search():
   term = flask.request.args.get('query')
   possibilities = [i for [i] in sqlite3.connect('filename.db').cursor().execute("SELECT * FROM stores") if term.lower() in i.lower()]
   return flask.jsonify({'html':'<p>No results found</p>' if not possibilities else '<ul>\n{}</ul>'.format('\n'.join('<li>{}</li>'.format(i) for i in possibilities))})
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Would this be able to work for MySQL too?

Comment: @Emily Glad to help! It will work with `MySql`, all you need to do is connect to your database which is running on your server, and then run `INSERT` and `SELECT` queries similar to `sqlite3`. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html)

Comment: thank you again! one last question, how do I display the filtered row inside the #results div?

Comment: @Emily The code above completes that task. In the route, a simple list is created which is passed as a jsonified object to the `ajax` response function. Let me know how this works.

Comment: @Ajax1234 hello :) how do you combine the html and python script? If I run the python script will not give me errors but when I activate the web page it doesn't give any result from the database. Instead of sqlite3 I am using PostgreSQL. Please help.