# Problem loading a web app using flask, python, HTML and PostgreSQL; not able to connect python and html scripts plus Internal Server Error message

Tags: python, html, postgresql, flask

Recently, I have started working on a new project : a web app which will take a name as an input from a user and as result outputs the database rows related to the user input. The database is created using PostgreSQL and in order to complete the task I am using Python as a programming language, followed by Flask (I am new to it) and HTML. I have created 2 source codes, 1 in Python as below :

```
import os
import psycopg2 as pg
import pandas as pd
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "<a href='/search'>Input a query</a>"

@app.route('/search')
def search():
    term = flask.request.args.get('query')
    db = pg.connect(
        host="***", 
        database="***", 
        user ="***",
        password="***")
    db_cursor = db.cursor()
    q = ('SELECT * FROM table1')
    possibilities = [i for [i] in db_cursor.execute(q) if term.lower() in i.lower()]
    return flask.jsonify({'html':'<p>No results found</p>' if not possibilities else '<ul>\n{}</ul>'.format('\n'.join('<li>{}</li>'.format(i) for i in possibilities))})

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

and HTML code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='text' name ='query' id='query'>
        <button type='button' id='search'>Search</button>
        <div id='results'></div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#search').click(function(){
            var text = $('#query').val();
            $.ajax({
            url: "/search",
            type: "get",
            data: {query: text},
            success: function(response) {
            $("#results").html(response.html);
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
            //Do Something to handle error
            }
        });
      });
     });
    </script>
</html>
```

For these scripts I read the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244721/how-to-take-html-user-input-and-query-it-via-python-sql).
These scripts are giving me troubles and I have two main questions :
First : How are these two source codes connected to each other? whenever I run the python script or the html, they look completly disconnected and are not functioning.Moreover, when I run the Python script it gives me this error message on the webpage :

> Internal Server Error
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

and this message on terminal :

> Serving Flask app 'userInferface' (lazy loading)
> Environment: production
> WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
> Use a production WSGI server instead.
> Debug mode: off
> Running on....

Can someone please help me by showing how can these 2 scripts connect and why am I getting such errors. Thank you.

Comment: Use `app.run(debug=True)` and [edit] the question to include the output please.

Comment: You need to keep the html file in in templates folder , and in function home `return flask.render_template('your_html_file.html')` and you need to add methods like this, `@app.route('/search',methods=['GET'])`. also please learn flask basics https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/

Comment: You need to read [Quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/) and [Tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/)

Comment: @charchit hello. thank you for your comment. I created the templates folder and stored the html file there but I am still having the same issue. this is my path C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\templates. Can you please help me?

Comment: you have to create templates folder in you directory where your python code is not in the flask package directory.

Comment: @charchit I suppose you are referring to the python code I created for this project. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `render_template` to connect Flask and your HTML code. 
 For example:

```
from flask import render_template

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```